# Add specific values from DataGridView to Listbox (Windows Forms / NET Framework 4.7)

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

In my DataGridView (DGV1)  I have a table with different string values (N1-N9). Some of these cell values are highlighted in yellow (this appears bold in the table (N1, N5, N6)). I want to add these selected cells in a ListBox as shown below.

[image]

```
var foundValues = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(row => new
                {
                    Name = row.Cells[row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(cell => cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText == "XX").ColumnIndex].Value,                    
                    ColorValue = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow).Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString()),
                    Count = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Count(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow),
                    
                }).ToArray();

                
                foreach (var s in foundValues)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add($"{s.Name}, {s.ColorValue}, {s.Count}");
                }
```

Unfortunately my output contains an error. The yellow highlighted cell values (strings) are not displayed in the ListBox.

```
DD1, System.Linq.Enumerable + WhereSelectEnumerableIterator‘2[SystemWindows.Forms.DataGridViewCell,System.String],1
DD2, System.Linq.Enumerable + WhereSelectEnumerableIterator‘2[SystemWindows.Forms.DataGridViewCell,System.String],2
DD3, System.Linq.Enumerable + WhereSelectEnumerableIterator‘2[SystemWindows.Forms.DataGridViewCell,System.String],0
```

Could anyone please help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to try checking on the `c.Style.BackColor` value. Maybe you need to convert to ARGB for the comparison as the named colors have special properties..

Comment: This does not work. With the following code the yellow marked cell values can be extracted from the DatagridView and displayed in the ListBox :  var cellColorValue = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                            .Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                            .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString()))
                            .ToArray();

Comment: listBox1.Items.AddRange(cellColorValue);

The only problem is that the marked cell values are listed among themselves.

Comment: _he marked cell values are listed among themselves._ What does that mean? Can you show the wrong result in your post?

Comment: The values are placed in one column one below the other: In this case, the selected cell values are displayed in the ListBox as follows : 
N1
N5
N6
What i would like therefore is, that the values in the listbox look like this:

D1, N1,1
D2, N5, N6, 2
D3, 0 (see figure above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My LINQ skills are amateur at best, however from the output in the `ListBox`…

```
DD1, System.Linq.Enumerable + WhereSelectEnumerableIterator‘2[SystemWindows.Forms.DataGridViewCell,System.String],1
```

It appears the second value is a “collection.” And this makes sense looking at the `ColorValue` variable…

```
ColorValue = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow).Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString()),
```

This may return more than ONE value… and each value would be a simple `string` like.. “N5” and “N6”, but the object is STILL a “collection.” Therefore, when you execute the code…

```
listBox1.Items.Add($"{s.Name}, {s.ColorValue}, {s.Count}");
```

And `s.ColorValue` is a “collection”… the `ListBox` isn’t smart enough to take that collection and turn it into a “single” comma separated `string` value.

Therefore, the code needs to do this “combining” of the different `string` values in the collection. I am guessing there is a way to do this using LINQ, but my feeble attempts failed and I ended up using the `String.Join` method to combine the `strings` in the collection.

In my tests, setting the `ColorValue` variable to the joined `strings` appears to work as you want.

The change I made is below using your code. This single change displayed the values properly in the `ListBox` as you have shown. Granted it appears you may need to fudge a little to get the proper comma placement, however this should be trivial.

```
ColorValue = String.Join(", ", row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow).Select(cell => cell.Value)),
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: It's amazing how that just little changes the whole code. Great work!! Thank you so much for your efforts JohnG!!!